# Parse.com nested query containing doesNotMatchQuery

Tags: android, ios, parse-platform, pfuser

I have `User` and `GroupMember` Class with parse.

I have a added a `User` pointer column in `GroupMember` Class and wanted to fetch all users from `User` Class but excluding which are present in `GroupMember` Class relation.

Comment: would you please give some examples such as GroupMember has these rows and columns and User has these rows and columns with values in them.  Fake data in these values will work.  We just need to know the specific logic you're looking for so we can give you the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make a two queries where You query all the users `objectId` from `GroupMember`s pointer column and then exclude those objects from the next query on `User` class.

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> a = ParseQuery.getQuery("GroupMember");
a.include("name of pointer column")
a.findInBackground(new FindCallback...); // get list of objects id with for each loop 
//i.e. for (ParseObject o : list) String s = o.getParseObject("user_pointer_column").getObjectId(); 
//then add it to some list

ParseQuery<ParseObject> b = ParseQuery.getQuery("User");
b.whereNotContainedIn("objectId", list_of_ids);
```

Or the other way:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> a = ParseQuery.getQuery("User");   
ParseQuery<ParseObject> b = ParseQuery.getQuery("GroupMember");
b.whereDoesNotMatchQuery("user_pointer_column", a);
b.findInBackground(new FindCallback...{...});
```

Comment: can we do it in single query?

Comment: looking for second kind of query, but I want all from "User" except some `GroupMember`s  <pointer_column>, no idea how to compare with `user` class. but thanks, first way is right.

Comment: though I am only looking for nested query.

Comment: No way of doing it in one, not compouned query - Parse limitations, though. If the first way is right - please accept it as an answer :)